# Java decrease memory usage

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I found out that if my application has much free memory available it uses  more memory than it needs. I heard that this behavior is common for all Java  applications but it's not acceptable for me.

So the question is how can I force Java to use less memory?

I know that I can call `System.gc()` manually every few seconds, but  is it alright to do so and are there any other methods?

**P.S.** my application is updated regularly on production server and I need to monitor memory usage for some leaks and so on (generally there are no leaks but if one appears I should see it as fast as possible), and also I need to predict the time when I should upgrade my hardware. All these things are very hard to do if jvm unpredictably changes its memory hunger. So the only thing I want is to force jvm to be predictable in memory usage (if number of users doubles memory should doubles too)

Comment: It may be time to re-think why it is not acceptable.  Can you give a technical reason, or is it something which makes you uncomfortable?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't do your testing on a production server?  And only deploy when you know there are no leaks?

Comment: this is not a testing, of course I have testing server too, but it runs with different load

Comment: It sounds like you need to memory profile your application so you understand how memory is being used.  Looking at the maximum memory you give the application is not very useful.  A better number to look at is how much memory is used after a GC.  Given the cost of memory is pretty low I suggest getting more memory than you are likely to need and you won't have to monitor it or upgrade the server later (saving money all round)

Comment: 32 GB : 8 x 4 GB Memory 1600 cost around $160. If you start with this much memory you might not need to monitor it, which could easily save this much memory over the life of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found out that if my application has much free memory available it uses more memory than it needs. I heard that this behavior is common for all Java applications but it's not acceptable for me.

It depends on what you mean "more memory than it needs".  If you mean, more than the minimum memory to represent your application's objects, then you are correct.

It is standard behavior that Java uses more memory than the bare minimum that it could theoretically get away with.  "Worse still", most JVMs don't give memory back to the OS ... even if that memory has been freed by the GC.  Both of these properties are *necessary* for efficient operation of a general purpose garbage collector.

If this is unacceptable to you, you should not be using a garbage collected language.  Use C or C++.  (But also be aware that it is unusual for C / C++ memory allocators to be able to give memory back to the OS either ... even if the implementation allows it.)

---

The positive side of this is that Java (and in fact any GC'ed language) will actually run better if you give it plenty of memory.  Modern GC's work more efficiently as the ratio of garbage to non-garbage increases, and a larger heap makes that happen.  (Of course, you can go too far, especially if the application is competing with other things for real memory.)

---

As other answers said, calling `System.gc()` does not help.  It is unlikely to result in any memory being given back.  Worse still, you'll most likely run the GC when the garbage level is too low for efficient operation, so you will be increasing CPU time for no benefit.

---

Concerning your "PS":

1. I don't think there is a way to (reliably) detect the existence of a memory leak ... apart from monitoring memory usage trends.
2. I don't think there is a way to (reliably) predict when you will new hardware ... apart from monitory memory usage (and other) trends.
3. I don't think there is a way to force you application's memory usage to be proportional to the number of users ... apart from designing / coding your application so that it scales in the way you want.

On the other hand, you could say the same thing about a C / C++ application.

Answer (score 7):

You can tell it to use less memory by calling java with the `-Xmx` parameter ie:

```
java -Xmx128M xxx
```

will run with a max of 128Mb ([by default in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) this is set to *"Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB"*)

Don't call `System.gc()` all the time...it's your time you'll be wasting ;-)

Also, why are you worrying about this?  When java gets near the maximum memory it's allowed, it will do a GC sweep anyways

Comment: no, I can't limit my application in memory because when it can stop working after several weeks (it is a server-side app and number of users grows, so I need as much memory as my server can provide)

Comment: Don't worry about it then...  Is it crashing?  If so, it could be a memory leak on your part, and no amount of `System.gc()` is going to fix that...

Answer (score 3):

First how is your FREE memory going to help if you call System.gc()? And calling System.gc() is not even a good option. If you want a more aggressive garbage collector there are policies for that. 
What you should do instead is start it with less memory with -Xmx

Answer (score 2):

No, is not alright. System.gc() does not guaranty if/when the garbage collector will start. More, System.gc() might call the garbage collector to often resulting in more time spent garbage collecting than running the application.

The solution is to determine the maximum amount of memory your application needs(footprint) and start the virtual machine with slightly more memory than the footprint. I assume here that  your application has no memory leaks.